# How to not completely collapse CollapsingToolbarLayout programmatically?

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have `CollapsingToolbarLayout` in `AppBarLayout`. Inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout` i have Toolbar with `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"`.
And I have `RecyclerView`. And when I scroll `RecyclerView` my `CollapsingToolbarLayout` at first collapse to size of Toolbar. Then it collapse completely.
To show behavior I made gif:

[image]

**And I have 3 states of CollapsingToolbarLayout:**

1) **Completely expanded**

[image]

2) **Collapsed to toolbar size**

[image]

3) **Completely Collapsed**

[image]

If I use method `setExpanded` of `CollapsingToolbarLayout` *i* can **Completely Collapsed** and  **Completely Expanded**  state.

And I wonder how to programmatically collapse `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to toolbar size (I show it in screenshot **Collapsed to toolbar size**).

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleGravity="start|center_vertical"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|enterAlways"
                app:title="">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/actor_activity_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: What do you want to have Toolbar when scrollup ?

Comment: Current behavior is good for me. It must work like it work now. But i need ability programmatically (without user interact ) collapse CollapsingToolbarLayout to toolbar size (I show it in screenshot Collapsed to toolbar size).

Comment: Do you wanna automatically scroll to top ?@Anton

Comment: I need to get state like in image https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dEX4m.png programmatically on some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"`

or

`app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"`

inside your   `<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout`

**Reference :** https://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout

**Full Code Here :**

```
  <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="start|center_vertical"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:title="">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/actor_activity_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Comment: I try you suggestion. But if i add exitUntilCollapsed my toolbar don't hided when i scroll recyclerview.